# Template override issue, doesn't show the content of child .html file

Tags: python, django-templates

Some why the simplest test of overriding a template doesn't works for me, i tried several times, searched the web and i still can't find the reason why its doesn't working properly like in the tutorials and youtube videos.

Checked all the urls, settings etc...
I've tried writing the simplest code to override the template.

/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sandbox 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

/main.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <p1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus 
        atque cum delectus ducimus id, impedit, incidunt laborum minus 
        officia,officiis porro saepe sed sunt tempore ullam veniam 
        voluptates. Odit,soluta?
    </p1>
{% endblock %}
```

Web page Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sandbox 1</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see that the is a newline where the

should appear, but its empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like this should work, though I'd suggest you try a few things just to match the Django [Template extending](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/) documentation more closely.

- Put the `block main` and `endblock` sections on different lines
- Use single quotes in `extends` block (probably shouldn't matter but
  who knows)

Also are you sure you're loading `main.html` into your webpage and not `index.html`? That is what `index.html` would look like by itself.

Comment: So emberresing I've actually loaded the index.html and not main.html. NOTE: base.html it's much better naming convention for the main template, otherwise you make dumb mistakes and load the base template instead of the one you actually should like I did... THANK YOU Sam!

Comment: Haha glad you found it! Happy coding!